# Implementing getElementsByClassName recursively

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion

Trying to hand-code `getElementsByClassName` recursively.

While the code works in my console, I'm not passing my test case in mocha. Assuming the test case was written correctly, what can I do to make my code better (read: more correct)?

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  var docBody = document.body;
  var classes = [];
  var walk = function (node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
      walk(node, func);
      node = node.sibling;
    }
  }
  walk(docBody, function() { 
    if (docBody.classList.contains(className)) {
      classes.push(docBody)
    }
  });
  return classes;
};
```

Comment: `node = node.sibling;` - do you mean `node = node.nextSibling;`?

Comment: What test case, and how does it fail?

Comment: Your `func` callback always only refers to `docBody`, not to the `node` that was passed to it.

Comment: @Bergi the test case uses Jquery to add a class called "targetClass" and then uses my function check that it returns "true". 

I saw that problem with the func callback, but in my walk function, the node (docBody) is continuously redfined. how would I rewrite it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems, as noted above: `node.sibling` should be `node.nextSibling`, and you need to look at the `node` passed to `walk()`, not always at `docBody`.

Additionally, some of the nodes you encounter (e.g. text nodes) won't *have* a `classList`, so account for that:

```js
var getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
  var docBody = document.body;
  var classes = [];

  var walk = function (node, func) {
    func(node);
    node = node.firstChild;
    while (node) {
      walk(node, func);
      node = node.nextSibling;
    }
  }

  walk(docBody, function(node) { 
    if (node.classList && node.classList.contains(className)) {
      classes.push(node)
    }
  });

  return classes;
};
```

Comment: Or even better, just use `.firstElementChild` and `.nextElementSibling`

Answer (score 1):

For a start, [objects implementing the `Element` interface have a `nextSibling` (and a `previousSibling`) property, not a `sibling` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#node), so your `while` loop always stops after the `.firstChild` as the property access evaluates to a false-value.

Next time, please [debug first](http://devtoolsecrets.com/).

Also, I recommend implementing this based on the return value of [`document.getElementsByTagName("*")`](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-document-getelementsbytagname) instead which already does the recursive traversal much more efficiently (since it uses native DOM code).

Your question sounds like a homework assignment. StackOverflow is there to help you solve *real problems* instead. Please read the FAQ on which questions are considered appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on devtoolsecrets. However, I checked against the FAQs and they do not specify that you cannot ask HW questions.